# publishing WCF Service .NET 3.5 on IIS

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, iis-7, web-config, was

I have a problem with  publishing WCF Service on IIS. I think - the problem is in configuration(web.config).
This my serviceModel section:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="rajon_wcf_service.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="rajon_wcf_service.Service1Behavior">                       
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="rajon_wcf_service.IService1">
                <!-- 
          После развертывания необходимо удалить или заменить указанный ниже элемент удостоверения, чтобы отображалось
          удостоверение, под которым выполняется развернутая служба. В случае удаления служба WCF автоматически определит соответствующее 
          удостоверение.
      -->
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>


<behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="rajon_wcf_service.Service1Behavior">
                <!-- Чтобы избежать разглашения сведений о метаданных, установите ниже значение FALSE и удалите вышеуказанную конечную точку метаданных перед развертыванием -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- Чтобы получить сведения об исключениях в ошибках для отладки, установите ниже значение TRUE. Перед развертыванием установите значение FALSE, чтобы избежать разглашения сведений об исключении -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I put URI: http://localhost/KOMPLAT/Service1.svc , I receive error message: HTTP 404.17 - Not Found

KOMPLAT is the name of my application on IIS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I FOUND!

The problem was in Windows Features!

Go to Windows Features() and check:
 Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation
and check
 Windows Communication Foundation Non - HTTP Activation.
Thats all.
[image]

Comment: Can I +1 more than once... please?  Thank you!!